# How do I get the 'Paris Visite' ticket?

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, paris

Where can I buy the [Paris Visite](http://www.transilien.com/static/tarifs/paris-visite) ticket? (I live in Brazil). Also, how do I calculate whether it is going to be cheaper than just buying single tickets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My opinion is that a Paris Visite pass is hardly worth the money.

If that's true in your case is difficult to answer. Basically, you have to use the public transport quite heavily. The price of single metro ticket is 1.70 EUR and if you buy tickets by a batch of 10 ("carnet"), the price goes down to 1.33 EUR per ticket. With that information in mind, take the Paris Visite pass you are interested in (1, 2,3 or 5 days), and calculate how often you would be able to take the public transport on regular tickets, ot how many [discounts](http://www.transilien.com/static/tarifs/paris-visite-avantages) you would have to use.

**Example**. A 2 day pass is 15.85 EUR. For a bit less than that, 15 EUR, you can buy 11 regular tickets (1 carnet and 1 single ticket). That's a lot for two days, especially if you plan your sightseeing a bit rationally.

And don't let yourself fool by the discounts. Some are more sexy, some other are less sexy. Check precisely what the discounts are good for, check the prices. And check if you are interested in these at all! Plan your sightseeing first, i.e. make a list of what your are interested in and see if that's covered by the pass. Don't do it the other way round. You might miss a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Paris Visite is a tourist trap.

Consider getting a Mobilis. This is what the locals use when they need to travel for an entire day. It's like the Paris Visite but there is no voucher booklet and it is much cheaper than the Paris Visite. Mobilis is valid on the publicly operated airport links (Orlybus, Roissybus, RER B, but not Orlyval or Le Bus Direct) (since 2018).

Mobilis  is available only in 1-day version. You can buy one for each day of travel, and modulate the cost by buying only the zones you need for that day.

Paris visite is only available in zones 1-3 or 1-5 version. Mobilis allows finer control.

If you stay from Monday to Sunday, buy a Navigo Découverte (smart card) and load it with a weekly pass.

Answer (score 4):

[In Paris](http://www.pariswelcome.net/metro/paris_visite.htm):

> Paris Visite pass can be purchased in all Paris Metro, RER, Transilien
>   SNCF stations, bus terminal ticket counters, RATP Boutiques, RATP
>   sales desks at Orly and CDG airports and Paris tourist offices.

From outside of Paris:

You can book it [online directly at Rail Europe](http://www.raileurope.com/activities/paris-visite/index.html).

Comment: The first link quotes obsolete prices!

Comment: @MarcelC. yeah, but I was using it as a source for where you can buy them, not the price :/  The live prices are available on the online booking at Rail Europe.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't change a lot and nothing about the fundamentals.

Comment: ... and nothing that will prevent me from an upvote

Answer (score 1):

An update to the other answers which state that (as was the case at the time) you couldn't use Mobilis to reach the airports.

Since January 1st, 2018, Mobilis zones 1-5 can be used to reach Charles-de-Gaulle via the RER (train), which wasn't the case before.

Note however that it still doesn't include Orlyval.

So this is another alternative to consider. Depending on the length of your stay, the specific days of the week you will be in Paris, and where and how much you wish to travel, you have the following options:

- Paris Visite (paper ticket, includes free travel in the chosen zones and discounts)
- Mobilis (paper ticket)
- Navigo Jour (requires a Navigo Smart Card, otherwise exactly equivalent to Mobilis)
- Navigo Semaine (if your stay aligns with a monday-sunday week)
- individual tickets for airport-to-Paris transfers + one or more "carnet(s)" (10 tickets) for travel inside Paris